# Gridgain : Requesting mapping from grid failed for platformId

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I have 3 node gridgain cluster deployed in google kubernetes engine. Time to time I got following error for caches. After recreating cache error not appear.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Requesting mapping from grid failed for [platformId=0, typeId=1223911690]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:378)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:333)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:320)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:673)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1724)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:904)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:167)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:198)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:77)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinariesIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:145)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinariesIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:87)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryCacheObjectsIterator.next(GridQueryCacheObjectsIterator.java:65)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryCacheObjectsIterator.next(GridQueryCacheObjectsIterator.java:30)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.AutoClosableCursorIterator.next(AutoClosableCursorIterator.java:57)
        at com.stl.sciocardio.webapp.event_service.repository.OrderRepository.getPatientViewAndDisclosureViewOrders(OrderRepository.java:260)
        at com.stl.sciocardio.webapp.event_service.repository.OrderRepository.getPatientViewOrders(OrderRepository.java:237)
        at com.stl.sciocardio.webapp.event_service.repository.OrderRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4af11081.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.stl.sciocardio.webapp.event_service.repository.OrderRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$594356f0.getPatientViewOrders(<generated>)
        at com.stl.sciocardio.webapp.event_service.service.OrderService.getPatientViewOrders(OrderService.java:38)
        at com.stl.sciocardio.webapp.event_service.controller.OrderController.getPatientViewOrders(OrderController.java:137)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Client application written in Java and running in kubernetes. Following is the configuration for client.

```
            IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
            cfg.setClientMode(true);

            cfg.setShutdownPolicy(ShutdownPolicy.GRACEFUL);
            KubernetesConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new KubernetesConnectionConfiguration();
            connectionConfiguration.setNamespace(System.getenv("NAMESPACE"));
            connectionConfiguration.setServiceName(System.getenv("SERVICE_NAME"));
            TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder(connectionConfiguration);
            cfg.setMetricsLogFrequency(0);
            cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));

            ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

No server side error in this time. What is the reason for this and how I solve this without breaking existing caches and data.

node-configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <property name="workDirectory" value="/gridgain-dev/work"/>
        <property name="shutdownPolicy" value="GRACEFUL"/>
        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="ScioCardio Gridgain Dev"/>

    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="walMode" value="FSYNC"/>
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>

                <property name="walPath" value="/gridgain-dev/wal"/>
                <property name="walArchivePath" value="/gridgain-dev/walarchive"/>
            </bean>

        </property>

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                        <property name="namespace" value="gridgain-dev"/>
                        <property name="serviceName" value="gridgain-service-dev"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: This is likely due to you not setting your working dir correctly. The above message usually appears when the marshaller dir(which is in inside the working dir) could not be found:
Use this guide to set up your K8 cluster: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.0/installation/kubernetes/gke-deployment.html

Comment: This time there is no any error in server side. Exception thrown in client side. Working directory setting in confuration xml. It added to question. Sometimes error fixed after rebuild maven client application. I need to identify exact reason for this

Comment: We are also facing similar issue intermittently in one of the env deployed in Kubernetes. GridGain version used : 8.8.10